# Need to create several smaller tables from one large table

Tags: java, list

I have a table of objects very similar to the below with each object having 4 columns `A`,`B` `C` and `D`.

```
A        B               C              D
---------------------------------------------------
Jan-13  AIR SHOPPING    TPF SCIPS   61
Feb-13  AIR SHOPPING    TPF SCIPS   81
Mar-13  AIR SHOPPING    TPF SCIPS   147
Jan-13  AVAILABILITY    TPF SCIPS   17007
Feb-13  AVAILABILITY    TPF SCIPS   1845
Mar-13  AVAILABILITY    TPF SCIPS   2297 
Jan-13  CONNECTIVITY    TPF SCIPS   1240
Feb-13  CONNECTIVITY    TPF SCIPS   1080
Mar-13  CONNECTIVITY    TPF SCIPS   1864
```

From the above table I need to create different tables based on column B. i.e. I need to create table of objects which has same column B value. Finally for the above table I need to create 3 different tables.

table-1

```
A        B               C              D
---------------------------------------------------
Jan-13  AIR SHOPPING    TPF SCIPS   61
Feb-13  AIR SHOPPING    TPF SCIPS   81
Mar-13  AIR SHOPPING    TPF SCIPS   147
```

table-2

```
A        B               C              D
---------------------------------------------------
Jan-13  AVAILABILITY    TPF SCIPS   17007
Feb-13  AVAILABILITY    TPF SCIPS   1845
Mar-13  AVAILABILITY    TPF SCIPS   2297
```

table-3

```
A        B               C              D
---------------------------------------------------
Jan-13  CONNECTIVITY    TPF SCIPS   1240
Feb-13  CONNECTIVITY    TPF SCIPS   1080
Mar-13  CONNECTIVITY    TPF SCIPS   1864
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried 2 D arraList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, guessing in this example you have an ArrayList of your own class (let's call it Row), I would do it like:

```
ArrayList<Row> bigList = new ArrayList<Row>();
//Insert all data
//...
Iterator i = bigList.iterator();
ArrayList<Row> listA = new ArrayList<Row>();
ArrayList<Row> listB = new ArrayList<Row>();
ArrayList<Row> listC = new ArrayList<Row>();
while(i.hasNext()){
  Row now = i.next();
  switch(now.getColumnB()){
    case "AIR SHOPPING":
      listA.add(now);
      break;
    case "AVAILABILITY":
      listB.add(now);
      break;
    case "CONNECTIVITY":
      listC.add(now);
      break;
  }
}
//And at this point you should have your lists
```

Well, I just guessed you have an iterable list and you have your own row object, but if you don't and you may have an `array[]` and full of `String`s the process shouldn't be very different.

Comment: `switch/case` doesn't work with `String`s in JDK 6 and lower

Comment: you can always use `if(...){}else if(...){}...else{}` as many times as you want if you can't use switch.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I'm using java 6. i was able to achive this with map

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to make a map first, since you are probably doing an assignment, that would mean looping through the list, adding each item to a map, where the key is the value in column b, then the value is a list to which the given item would be added. Be careful to check if the list has not been initialized. Then you can loop through the map and dump each individual list quite easily.

Comment: thanks for the response. i got some code of yr explanation and made my work easier :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Objname> list=new ArrayList<>();
    //add data to list

    Map<String,List<Objname>> map=new HashMap<>(); 

    for(Objname o:list)
    {
            if(map.keySet().contains(o.getB()))
                map.get(o.getB()).add(o);
            else
            {
                List<Objname> temp=new ArrayList<Objname>();
                temp.add(o);
                map.put(o.getB(),temp);
            }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a ton. u made my work very easy